# Creating time-series chart out of list in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I have reduced a band/variable of daily image collection to monthly collection. The function returns a list containing objects with 2 properties. Like this
[image]

I want to plot a time-series chart of all the elements (n=90) with date value on x-axis and tasmin on Y-Axis.

Which chart type should I use and how to obtain this in code?

This is my code

```
// load data
var dataset_45 = ee.ImageCollection('NASA/NEX-GDDP')
                  .filter(ee.Filter.eq('scenario','rcp45'))
                  .select(['tasmin']);




var tasmin_monthly = ee.List.sequence(0, 89).map(function(n){
  var start = ee.Date('2015-03-20').advance(n, 'month');
  var end = start.advance(1, 'month');
  var monthtemp =  dataset_45.filterDate(start, end)
                      .mean()
                      .reduceRegion({
                      reducer: 'mean',
                      geometry: geometry,
                      scale: 27830
                      });
  return monthtemp.set('system:time_start', start);
});

print(tasmin_monthly);
var min = tasmin_monthly.get(0)
print(min)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can turn your list into a `FeatureCollection` and then chart it:

```
var tasmin_monthly = ee.FeatureCollection(
  ee.List.sequence(0, 89).map(function(n) {
    var start = ee.Date('2015-03-20').advance(n, 'month')
    var end = start.advance(1, 'month')
    var monthtemp = dataset_45.filterDate(start, end)
      .mean()
      .reduceRegion({
        reducer: 'mean',
        geometry: geometry,
        scale: 27830
      })
    return ee.Feature(null, monthtemp)
      .set('system:time_start', start)
  })
)

print(tasmin_monthly)

var chart = ui.Chart.feature.byFeature({
  features: tasmin_monthly, 
  xProperty: 'system:time_start', 
  yProperties: ['tasmin']
})

print(chart)
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/4dab71a796cc729b672c83bfe17fdcdd

Comment: Thank you Daniel, it worked